# How to fill a rectangle with lab color?

Tags: c#, .net-core, .net-6.0, itext7

I want to fill a rectangle with lab color, how do I go about it? I know itextsharp has a PdfLabColor class, but itext7 doesn't, it seems to be a weakening feature.

```
float[] labValues = { 35.76f, 26.74f, -35.51f };
var targetPdfPath = @"e:\labcolor.pdf";
using (PdfDocument pdfDoc = new PdfDocument(new PdfWriter(targetPdfPath)))
{
    var pageSize = PageSize.A4;
    Document doc = new Document(pdfDoc, pageSize);
    var page = pdfDoc.AddNewPage(pageSize);
    PdfCanvas pdfCanvas = new PdfCanvas(page);

    Color labColor = null;//how to get a lab color?

    pdfCanvas.SaveState();
    pdfCanvas.SetFillColor(labColor);
    pdfCanvas.Rectangle(100f, pageSize.GetHeight() - 200, 100f, 100f);
    pdfCanvas.FillStroke();
    pdfCanvas.RestoreState();
    pdfDoc.Close();
}
```

Comment: have you tried using [Lab](https://api.itextpdf.com/iText/dotnet/latest/classi_text_1_1_kernel_1_1_colors_1_1_lab.html) to set your fill color?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [Lab class](https://api.itextpdf.com/iText/dotnet/latest/classi_text_1_1_kernel_1_1_colors_1_1_lab.html) to set your fill color, with the following arguments:

```
Lab(float[] whitePoint, float[] blackPoint, float[] range, float[] value)
```

and then just use it with your canvas:

```
pdfCanvas.SetFillColor(new Lab());
```

this is what PdfLabColor looked like, so it should be easy to make a transition between PdfLabColor and Lab.

```
PdfLabColor(float[] whitePoint, float[] blackPoint, float[] range)
```

Comment: A good answer would show **how** to use the `Lab` class to set the fill color.

Comment: that's fair, but I'm not familiar with lab color myself, but the API seems pretty obvious if you're familiar with lab color. sorry for the low effort friends.